# Simple data.table snippet fails when run in testthat unit test

Tags: r, data.table, testthat

I get errors when running devtools::test() with the single test file, shown below.  Yet, **when running the`test_that` statement on its own (or the code within, line-by-line), it works perfectly**, i.e. myDt1 has one column (y) and myDt has two columns (x and z), the `expect_equal` statements are satisfied, no fail, no run time error...

Surely, I must be doing something wrong, but I can't see the obvious!  This seems related to the features of `data.table` which rely on NSE (Non-Standard Evaluation), tentatively conflicting with some of the NSE and other magic which testthat uses?

Help!

```
context("data.table and testthat do not play nice ?")
library(data.table)

test_that("data.table ", {

  # the following runs perfectly on it own
  # but fails when run as a test.
  myDt <- data.table(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))
  targetCols <- c("y")

  myDt1 <- myDt[, targetCols, with=FALSE]
  expect_equal(ncol(myDt1), 1)

  myDt2 <- myDt[, !targetCols, with=FALSE]
  expect_equal(ncol(myDt2), 2)
})
```

The errors I get when in test mode are:
The "1. Failure" is due to the fact myDt1 didn't get created, it is NULL, without producing an error.  The "2. Error" indicates that the `!targetCols` doesn't get interpreted properly.  Neither of these happen when run outside of the devtool::test() framework.

```
> devtools::test()
Loading myLib
Testing myLib
data.table and testthat do not play nice ?: 12

Failed -----------------------------
1. Failure: data.table  (@testSimple.R#9) ----------------
ncol(myDt1) not equal to 1.
target is NULL, current is numeric


2. Error: data.table  (@testSimple.R#11) -----------------
invalid argument type
1: myDt[, !targetCols, with = FALSE] at D:\GitRepos\BlueMoon/tests/testthat/testSimple.R:11
2: `[.data.table`(myDt, , !targetCols, with = FALSE) at D:\GitRepos\BlueMoon/tests/testthat/testSimple.R:11
3: `[.data.frame`(x, i, j)

DONE ========================================================================
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:
There was no `import(data.table)` command in the NAMESPACE file.
Adding it solved the issue.   In my case, I added it *indirectly*, since I use roxygen, i.e. with

```
#' @import data.table
NULL
```

in one -or several- of the source files.  Here, commenting a NULL object, but that could also be any one of the function which uses the data.table library.  (When said usage is pervasive, there's no real benefit to adding these in a way that tracks all functions that use the package).